# Convert function into jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function abbrNum(number){
    var decPlaces = Math.pow(10, 3);
    var abbrev = ["k", "m", "b", "t", "qd", "qi", "sx", "sp", "oc", "n", "d"];
    for (var i = abbrev.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var size = Math.pow(10, (i+1) * 3);
        if(size <= number){
            number = Math.round(number*decPlaces/size)/decPlaces;
            if((number == 1000) && (i < abbrev.length - 1)){
                number = 1;
                i++
            }
            number += abbrev[i];
            break;
        }           
    }
    return number;
}
```

I want to convert it into a plugin called for example `format`, which gets some text from a span, runs it through this function, set the text of the same span the result it gets from the function.

So, now if you run the function it works like this:

```
abbrNum(123456); //123.456k
abbrNum(12345678); //12.345m
```

So I want to be able to select a span, change it's text, and then format it, something like:

```
$('span').text(1234).format(); //set span text to 1.234k
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to start with the documentation: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plugin from the function you have, using jQuery's `text()` method

```js
$.fn.format = function(){
    this.text(function(_, number) {
        var decPlaces = Math.pow(10, 3);
        var abbrev = ["k", "m", "b", "t", "qd", "qi", "sx", "sp", "oc", "n", "d"];
        for (var i = abbrev.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            var size = Math.pow(10, (i+1) * 3);
            if(size <= number){
                number = Math.round(number*decPlaces/size)/decPlaces;
                if((number == 1000) && (i < abbrev.length - 1)){
                    number = 1;
                    i++
                }
                number += abbrev[i];
                break;
            }           
        }
        return number;
    });
}

$('span').text(1234).format();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest way.

```
$.fn.pluginName = function() {
    // Your Code
};
```

Comment: That won't work. The existing code expects the text to be formatted to come from the function argument, and returns the result instead of writing it to the DOM.

Comment: How readest thou? *...which gets some text from a span, runs it through this function, set the text of the same span the result it gets from the function.* @Quentin?

Comment: @PeterKA — And if you put the OP code where JohaanThor said to put it, then it won't do that. It won't get it from a span. It won't run it through the function. It won't set the text of the span.

Comment: Yes @Quentin, I now see that we are on the same page. @JohannThor does have to adjust the code so at to `read` from and `write` to the span. :)